# Which packages of angular are present in the final build

Tags: angular, build-dependencies

I would like to know if there is a tool to track packages that are present in the final build of an angular project.

**For example** :
I have a package **"@angular/compiler"** which is a dependency of the package.json but not a dev dependency.

As mentioned on the angular docs https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#ahead-of-time-aot-compilation with **AOT compiler** code is already compiled, unlike JIT compiler. In my understanding, it means that the final build does not need @angular/compiler as a dependency if the flag AOT is set for the final build.

Is my reasoning is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see exactly what ends up in the production bundle by using a tool called [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer).

1. Build your Angular project with the `--stats-json` flag: `ng build --prod --stats-json`
2. Run `npx webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/{your-project-name}/stats.json` which will open a browser window with an interactive chart displaying the included dependencies (you can even search for a specific module).